# Glass: Null pointer exception when trying to add image to Static Card

Tags: android, service, nullpointerexception, photo, google-glass

I have a simple Glass app using the GDK to grab some text & take a photo.  I can easily create a LiveCard w/ the text & photo, however when I try to convert the live card to a static card, I get a null pointer exception when I try to add the image to the card.  here's a snippet of my code.  If i remove the call to addImage() it posts the card just fine.

```
        Card c = new Card(CompPlayerService.this);
        c.setText("you took a picture of " + MyService.this.personName);
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(picturePath); 
        c.addImage( uri);  //<-- this is throwing the NPE
        timelineManager.insert(c);
```

When I set a breakpoint in the service, I can see that the value of picturePath is NOT null and is the same exact path I use when I post the photo to a live card from the same service, which works fine.  here's the exception I get:

```
02-17 15:32:25.049  14120-14120/com.example.glassapp E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.google.android.glass.app.Card.addImage(Card.java:176)
```

Comment: You are reading the stack trace wrong. The NPE is inside the method addImage for the class Card, not at that line of code, but one deeper. Card.java line 176, you'd have to look at that code. I'd guess the URI doesn't point to a valid image.

Comment: Then why does the exact same image work on a live card?

Comment: No idea. Which is why I didn't propose an answer, only that the NPE isn't actually in your code, but one level deeper. And since removing the line works one can only assume it is something at least tangentially related to the uri. Maybe output uri.toString so we can see it, that may give someone else an idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<strike>What is the value of `picturePath`? My hunch is that you're passing a simple filesystem path instead of a valid `file:` URI.</strike>

You may want to consider using the `Uri.fromFile` method instead of `Uri.parse` to handle this correctly.

**UPDATE:** The `Card` class no longer supports calling `addImage` with a `Uri` argument. Instead, load the image into a `Bitmap` and call `addImage(Bitmap)`.

Comment: awesome, that did the trick!  makes me question Uri.parse though... seems like that should work as well...